# Relacionamento (Banco de Dados) (Sql)

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

por gentileza:

Eu não consigo entender o seguinte caso:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O meu problema seria a sintaxe usada na parte (1,1) -- (1,N)

No caso seria, 1 Departamento lota N funcionários e 1 Funcionário pode estar em apenas 1 departamento. Até aí tudo bem, mas a cardinalidade dos elementos entre os parênteses que me atrapalha.

Fazendo o (1,1) e (1,N), como eu chego a conclusão que esse relacionamento é 1 : N? Pego o primeiro elemento de "Departamento" e o segundo elemento de "Funcionário" e chego nessa conclusão?

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve pegar sempre a relação mais forte, no caso o N.

Não esqueça que o losango 'lotacao' serve apenas para orientar sua cabeça e perceber que tipo de relação existe entre as duas tabelas. A relação de 1 para N prevalece pois o N pesa sempre mais.

Se você tivesse (N:1) -- (1:N) ficaria (N:N) e teria de criar uma tabela associativa pois se trataria de uma relação de muitos para muitos.

Se tivesse (1:N) -- (1:1) ficaria (N:1).

Espero ter ajudado!